# Partly flatten nested JSON objects stored in df column

Tags: python, json, pandas, typeerror, json-normalize

I have a dataframe with 3 columns (**INSTNR**, **Enhedsadresser**, **API_response**), where the 3rd column (**API_response**) contains JSON objects. I would like to flatten the JSON object and store the extracted information in separate columns within the same df. I am particularly interested in extracting **kategori**, **resultater -> adresse -> id**, and **resultater -> adresse -> adgangsadresseid** information.

I have tried:

```
data = json_normalize(data=df['API_response'], record_path='resultater',
                            meta=['kategori'], errors='ignore')
```

but it simply returns ***TypeError: string indices must be integers***

Whereas `data = json_normalize(data=df['API_response'])` gave me a column with a list of indices...

**How can I extract the needed information?**

Example of a JSON object:

```
{
  "kategori": "A",
  "resultater": [
    {
      "adresse": {
        "id": "0a3f50bc-f815-32b8-e044-0003ba298018",
        "vejnavn": "Staldgaardsgade",
        "adresseringsvejnavn": "Staldgaardsgade",
        "husnr": "39A",
        "supplerendebynavn": null,
        "postnr": "7100",
        "postnrnavn": "Vejle",
        "status": 1,
        "virkningstart": "2009-11-24T02:15:25.000Z",
        "virkningslut": null,
        "adgangsadresseid": "0a3f5090-edef-32b8-e044-0003ba298018",
        "etage": "st",
        "dør": "th",
        "href": "https://api.dataforsyningen.dk/adresser/0a3f50bc-f815-32b8-e044-0003ba298018"
      },
      "aktueladresse": {
        "id": "0a3f50bc-f815-32b8-e044-0003ba298018",
        "vejnavn": "Staldgaardsgade",
        "adresseringsvejnavn": "Staldgaardsgade",
        "husnr": "39A",
        "supplerendebynavn": null,
        "postnr": "7100",
        "postnrnavn": "Vejle",
        "status": 1,
        "virkningstart": "2009-11-24T02:15:25.000Z",
        "virkningslut": null,
        "adgangsadresseid": "0a3f5090-edef-32b8-e044-0003ba298018",
        "etage": "st",
        "dør": "th",
        "href": "https://api.dataforsyningen.dk/adresser/0a3f50bc-f815-32b8-e044-0003ba298018"
      },
      "vaskeresultat": {
        "variant": {
          "vejnavn": "Staldgaardsgade",
          "husnr": "39A",
          "etage": "st",
          "dør": "th",
          "supplerendebynavn": null,
          "postnr": "7100",
          "postnrnavn": "Vejle"
        },
        "afstand": 0,
        "forskelle": {
          "vejnavn": 0,
          "husnr": 0,
          "postnr": 0,
          "postnrnavn": 0,
          "etage": 0,
          "dør": 0
        },
        "parsetadresse": {
          "vejnavn": "Staldgaardsgade",
          "husnr": "39A",
          "etage": "st",
          "dør": "th",
          "postnr": "7100",
          "postnrnavn": "Vejle"
        },
        "ukendtetokens": [],
        "anvendtstormodtagerpostnummer": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Link to API response containing this JSON object:  https://api.dataforsyningen.dk/datavask/adresser?betegnelse=Staldgaardsgade%2039A%20st%20th,%207100%20Vejle

**EDIT 1**

I created GitHub repo with data and python script: https://github.com/mantasbacys/TREFOR

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? I.e. how do you create your `df`?

Comment: It is just a simple `pd.read_excel`. I attached a link to GitHub repository with the files (last line in the post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Series.str.get](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) can help you extract individual elements from a dictionary column.

If `API_response` is a column of dictionaries formatted as your example, you can use:

```
df['kategori'] = df['api_response'].str.get('kategori')
df['id'] = (
    df['api_response']
    .str.get('resultater')  # get resultater object
    .str.get(0)  # get first element in list
    .str.get('adresse')
    .str.get('id')
)
df['adgangsadresseid'] =  = (
    df['api_response']
    .str.get('resultater')  # get resultater object
    .str.get(0)  # get first element in list
    .str.get('adresse')
    .str.get('adgangsadresseid')
)
```

Note that this will fail if the format doesn't match, so double check! E.g. if there are multiple elements in the `resultater` list, you may want to use [Series.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) instead.

---

**EDIT:**

Your file shows that `API_response` column actually contains parsed JSON dictionaries saved as *strings*. This means `.str.get` methods do not work as the values are not valid dictionaries.

As a quick fix, you should convert the dictionary strings to actual dictionaries *first*:

```
def convert(s): 
    """Convert dictionary string to JSON-like format and parse with json module"""
    s = s.replace("'", '"')
    s = s.replace("None", "null")
    return json.loads(s)

df['api_response'] = df.API_response.apply(convert)
# Alternative - UNSAFE! (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)
# df['api_response'] = df.API_response.apply(eval)
```

I am assuming this is happening because you first download the data, then you parse it into a dictionary, and save in a file before you load it again. This conversion to a string column happens as you save the file.

To avoid this conversion to string and back, try parsing the JSON and extracting values of interest in a single script.

Comment: I get this when I run the code: `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`
Isnt it because `.str` method cannot be used with dictionary? All cells in `API_response` column are formatted in the same way as my example.

Comment: Which line is throwing this error? `.str` can be used on different `object` columns, assuming the format is correct

Comment: I get it on line 4: `.str.get('resultater')`

Comment: See edit; also - alternatively, you can use `.str[item]` instead of `.str.get(item)`

Comment: Great, it worked like a charm after conversion to dict when I changed your code line to `df['API_response'].str.get('resultater').str[0].str.get('adresse').str.get('id')`! Thanks for taking time to help!